# android CalenderView click/touch listener over the date

Tags: android

i am a beginner in android. I tried for selecting a date on click/touch over the date of CalenderView. `setOnDateChangeListener` is ok, but it make me to select a date compulsory other than the selected date shown during the pop up of CalenderView. Is there any other way to solve this.

please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: yes but only for the first time he need to change the date if it popes. Is there any other listeners other than setOnDateChangeListener or any other tricks ...

Comment: okay, so you don't want to change date each time , it should be not editable, is it like that ?

Comment: yes. when calender is shown, the selected date is 10. if the user again click on 10(that is he don't want to change date on seeing the calender), nothing will happen using "setOnDateChangeListener" but i need to dispose the calender.